# Determine Equation of Average Acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, centripetal-force

Below are screenshots of the questions.
Below the images are my solutions.
(**I am only stumped on the last question**).

Text in image:

```
A cylinder of mass m moves around a circle attached to a string as shown
to the right. The radius of the circle is r and it moves around the circle with
a constant speed v.

Draw a (correctly oriented) vector showing the velocity of the cylinder at position B.

Draw a vector diagram showing the change in velocity of the cylinder between position A and position B. Make
sure that your vector representation Δv = v_B - v_A is correctly oriented. Draw all three vectors, v_A, v_B, and Δv.

Find the magnitude of the average acceleration of the cylinder over the interval from A to B in terms of r and v.
```

[image: Determine Vectors]

[image: Determine Equation of Average Acceleration]

My Attempts (none of them correct):

$a_{avg}$ = $v^2 \over r$
{Equation from data sheet}

$a_{avg}$ = $(v_B - v_A)^2 \over r$
{Using resultant vector}

$a_{avg}$ = $(\sqrt{(v_B - v_A)^2})^2 \over r$
{Since it wants *magnitude* of average acceleration, use magnitude of resultant vector}

For completeness,
the velocity vector at position B is an arrow pointing up that is the same length as the one in position A
Δv is an arrow pointing from the lower-left corner to the top-right corner that is slightly larger than $v_A$ and $v_B$

---

**EDIT:** My question is, "How do I determine an equation for $a_{avg}$, given the above information, in terms of r and v"

Comment: You haven't asked a question

Comment: Hi. Please show some of your reasoning. This is not a 'check my work ' site.

Comment: @D.Ennis My question is, "How do I determine an equation for $a_{avg}$ given the above information"

Comment: @Gert I'm not sure what more you would like other than the explanation in brackets below each of my incorrect attempts

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted the fact that acceleration is a vector and so done a scalar subtraction rather than a vector subtraction.
You have two acceleration vectors $\vec a_A$ and $\vec a_B$ both pointing towards the centre of the circle at $90^\circ$ to one another but of the same magnitude.
You first have to find the magnitude of the change in acceleration $\vec a_B -\vec a_A$ which might be helped if you draw a vector diagram.
You then need to find the time taken to go from $A$ to $B, \Delta t,$ knowing that the mass has undergone a quarter of a revolution of the circle.

The average acceleration is $\dfrac{|\vec a_B -\vec a_A|}{\Delta t}$